# I need to download files using selenium but I have 401 error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Since the website https://bourse.boursobank.com/bourse/opcvm/cours/0P0000RRUT/ modifies its name, I cannot run this code that I ran dynamically through a script daily before:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from datetime import date, datetime
import pandas as pd
import time
import os

website = "https://bourse.boursobank.com/bourse/opcvm/cours/0P0000RRUT/"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options
)
driver.minimize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get(website)

refuse_cookies_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="didomi-notice-agree-button"]'))
)
refuse_cookies_button.click()
download_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (
            By.XPATH,
            '//*[@class="c-quote-chart__menu-button-icon c-icon c-icon--download"]',
        )
    )
)
download_button.click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

**What I expect**: download the text file **AMUNDIFDSSBIFMINDIAEQAEURC_yyyy-mm-dd.txt**

**The actual behavior**: a 401 error response from this website https://api.boursobank.com/services/api/files/download.phtml?token=84e6d039f281ff0c6ab807a9b2ca0df703ec083819d2b7f552d9add654dba8db

> Msg : 401 V Not Authorized

no message in the header to know how to authenticate correctly (I tried to copy the link in a window I opened previously and it worked so I know I need to add some configurations before I do the driver.get(website).

Thanks in advance

I tried to accept the cookies but it didn't help. I inspected the AP response but no detail in it.

Comment: _no message in the header to know how to authenticate correctly_ Why would you expect such a message?  The website thinks you're a human.  A human would never see such a message, so it would be a waste.  I imagine there is readable text somewhere on the page that explains how to authenticate.

Comment: @JohnGordon I tried to find a solution to resolve an 401 error and this french website suggests to inspect the response header https://kinsta.com/fr/base-de-connaissances/erreur-401/. The only message I got on the page is  **Msg : 401 V Not Authorized**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the boursorama itself, and now it has been fixed, I wrote a simple code like yours and it was ok

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).